# How to create lines to seperate the items in the menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, lines

I would like to create 3 white lines, each individually to seperate "home", "about me" and "What I love" in the menu-bar. I have already created the lines for the border, but I am finding it hard to seperate the items itself with 1px solid white. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>It's all about me!</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <img src="me.jpg" alt="devon">
</div>
<h1>Ben's blog</h1>
<div class="grow">
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What I love</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
           ------------------(CSS below, in another file)-------------------------
body {
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
}


header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
img {
    border: 7px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;

}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;


}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

.grow {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: You should set the border to the `li` and not the `ul` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/noro690p/) mate.

Comment: Like Harry said - Set the border to the `<li>` and you could add `li:first-child { border-left: 0; }` to remove the first one. You can get: first-child to work in IE8, whereas :last-child / :not will not.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, all done :)

Comment: @BenjaminSunderland: Glad we could help mate. By the way, you should mark answers as accepted when it helped you solve the problem. That not only helps future readers but also serves as an acknowledgement of the effort put in by the answerers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following:

```
ul li:not(:last-child){
    border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

Remove `:not(:last-child)` if you wish to have a trailing line.

Comment: @BenjaminSunderland - great, if this is what you used dont forget to click the tick to accept the answer for the benefit of future users